# How to put an image into selected postition and store in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, image, drop-down-menu

What i have is a page to upload images and save their path into database with priority of the images.
Now this is just an example i have a 5 images in my database with their priority like

```
ID  ImageName  Description  Path  Priority
 1    1.jpg      Hello      xxxx   1
 2    2.jpg       hi        xxxx   2
 3    3.jpg       how       xxxx   3
 4    4.jpg       good      xxxx   4
 5    5.jpg       bye       xxxx   5
```

In my page i have File-Uploader control to upload file and drop-down list for priority in which priority comes from database.

Now my question is when i browse image to upload and select priority from drop-down list 
image should place at that priority and priority for that image increase by 1 and so on like

if i want to upload image number 6 and store it at 3 priority then database should be like this

```
ID  ImageName  Description  Path  Priority
 1    1.jpg      Hello      xxxx   1
 2    2.jpg       hi        xxxx   2
 6    6.jpg       you       xxxx   3
 3    3.jpg       how       xxxx   4
 4    4.jpg       good      xxxx   5
 5    5.jpg       bye       xxxx   6
```

This is my code for upload image.aspx.cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoNumber(); 
}
public void AutoNumber()
{     
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(Priority) as Tot FROM TestImages", con);
    SqlDataReader dr;

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(dr["tot"]);

        if (i > 0)
        {
            int j = i + 1;
            lblPriority.Text = "0" + j.ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            lblPriority.Text = "1";
        }

    }
    con.Close();
}
protected void btnSubmit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebGallery"].ConnectionString;
    string Priority = lblPriority.Text.Trim();
    //Get Filename from fileupload control
    string imgName = fileuploadimages.FileName.ToString();
    //sets the image path
    string imgPath = "Images/"+""+ddlDepartment.SelectedValue+"/";
    bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
    if (!IsExists)
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(imgPath));        
    //then save it to the Folder
    fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath+imgName));
    //Open the database connection
    con.Open();
    //Query to insert images name and Description into database
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into TestImages(ImageName,Description,Path,Priority) values(@ImageName,@Description,@Path,@Priority)" + "Update TestImages set Priority=Priority+1 where Priority='" + ddlPriority.SelectedValue + "'", con);
    //Passing parameters to query
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", imgName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", tbImageName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", imgPath + imgName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Priority", lblPriority.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Close dbconnection
    con.Close();
    tbImageName.Text = string.Empty;     
}   
}
```

there is has no error it update as well as insert but it will not insert at the selected priority from the drop-down list it will add at the last and update the priority.

How can i put image from the selected priority
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got my answer

```
 protected void ChangePriority_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebGallery"].ConnectionString;
    string DepartmentID = ddlDepartment.SelectedValue;
    string Description = tbImageName.Text.Trim();
    //string Priority = lblPriority.Text.Trim();
    string Priority = ddlPriority.SelectedValue;
    //Get Filename from fileupload control
    string imgName = fileuploadimages.FileName.ToString();
    //sets the image path if exist then store image in that place else create one
    string imgPath = "Images/Departments/" + "" + ddlDepartment.SelectedValue + "/";
    bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
    if (!IsExists)
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
    //then save it to the Folder
    fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath + imgName));
    //Open the database connection
    con.Open();
    //Query to insert * into images into database

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Images set Priority=Priority+1 where Priority>='" + ddlPriority.SelectedValue + "'" + "Insert into Images(ImageName,Description,Path,Priority,DepartmentID) values(@ImageName,@Description,@Path,@Priority,@DepartmentID)", con);
    //Passing parameters to query
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", imgName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Description);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", imgPath + imgName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Priority", Priority);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentID", DepartmentID);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Close dbconnection
    con.Close();
    tbImageName.Text = string.Empty;
   // Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update each row in your DB. Try something like this :

```
Image newImage;        //Your image uploaded
List<Image> listImages; //All the images from your DB (before insertion)

foreach(Image img in listImages) {
   if(img['Priority'] < newImg['Priority']) 
   {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                  "UPDATE TestImage SET Priority=" + img['Priority'] - 1 + ";"); 
   }
   else
   {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                  "UPDATE TestImage SET Priority=" + img['Priority'] + 1 + ";"); 

   }

}
```

Comment: where i have to place that code in my page load or on button click or on selectindex chage of dropdown list

Comment: i get what you want say but where to place that code so that it will work for me can you show me by putting that code in my code

Comment: You can use it before the insertion of your new image.

Comment: because when i place that code before insertion it will give me many error

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' this the error i got