# how to place image into database according to user selection

Tags: c#, database, image, drop-down-menu, asp.net-4.0

I have an upload image page in which I have a file uploader control and one drop-down list. The flow of my code is as follows:

First, user selects a file from the system using the file up-loader and then selects department from the drop-down list and clicks on submit button. When user clicks on the submit button, the image path is saved in the database and image is save into the selected department folder.

This is my aspx.cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoNumber();
}
public void AutoNumber()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(Priority) as Tot FROM Images", con);
    SqlDataReader dr;

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(dr["tot"]);

        if (i > 0)
        {
            int j = i + 1;
            lblPriority.Text = "0" + j.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            lblPriority.Text = "1";
        }

    }
    con.Close();
}
protected void btnSubmit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebGallery"].ConnectionString;
    string DepartmentID = ddlDepartment.SelectedValue;
    string Description = tbImageName.Text.Trim();
    string Priority = lblPriority.Text.Trim();

    //Get Filename from fileupload control
    string imgName = fileuploadimages.FileName.ToString();
    //sets the image path if exist then store image in that place else create one
    string imgPath = "Images/Departments/" + "" + ddlDepartment.SelectedValue + "/";
    bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
    if (!IsExists)
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
    //then save it to the Folder
    fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath + imgName));
    //Open the database connection
    con.Open();
    //Query to insert * into images into database
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Images(ImageName, Description, Path, Priority,DepartmentID) values (@ImageName, @Description, @Path, @Priority,@DepartmentID)", con);
    //Passing parameters to query
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", imgName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Description);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", imgPath + imgName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Priority", lblPriority.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentID", DepartmentID);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Close dbconnection
    con.Close();
    tbImageName.Text = string.Empty;
}
}
```

Now what I want is:

Now I want add one more drop-down list which items are sorted depending on the priority of images stored in the database.
When user browses an image, selects a department and selects a priority value for that image, a databse record is stored at that priority and image which is already at that image move by 1 and so on till the last image.

This is my related reference question. There I did'nt get any solution so I thought to modify my question and ask again. I hope you don't mind guys:

[How to put an image into selected postition and store in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209459/how-to-put-an-image-into-selected-postition-and-store-in-database/17210510?noredirect=1#comment24930508_17210510)

Comment: Thanks anar for the edit

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got what i want i guess this will help some one else too this is my code on button to add images for the selected priority

```
protected void ChangePriority_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string DepartmentID = ddlDepartment.SelectedValue;
    string Description = tbImageName.Text.Trim();

    string Priority = ddlPriority.SelectedValue;
    //Get Filename from fileupload control
    string imgName = fileuploadimages.FileName.ToString();
    //sets the image path if exist then store image in that place else create one
    string imgPath = "Images/Departments/" + "" + ddlDepartment.SelectedValue + "/";
    bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
    if (!IsExists)
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
    //then save it to the Folder
    fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath + imgName));
    //Open the database connection
    con.Open();
    //Query to insert * into images into database

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Images set Priority=Priority+1 where Priority>='" + ddlPriority.SelectedValue + "'" + "Insert into Images(ImageName,Description,Path,Priority,DepartmentID) values(@ImageName,@Description,@Path,@Priority,@DepartmentID)", con);
    //Passing parameters to query
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", imgName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Description);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", imgPath + imgName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Priority", Priority);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentID", DepartmentID);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Close dbconnection
    con.Close();
    tbImageName.Text = string.Empty;
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```